# How to stop Chrome (on Android) from opening a certain website for joining to Telegram Channels?

Tags: chrome-for-android, telegram

On my Android on a mobile set, I recently have encountered a problem. I have Chrome and Telegram installed. The Chrome repeatedly and automatically open a link like https://t.me/joinchat/.... which invites a person to join a Telegram Channel. After this page, it automatically switch to Telegram Messenger which pop-up the same message box for joining the channel.

I don't know whether the source of this pop-up is Chrome or Telegram. Anyway I restricted people who can invite me to Channels on Telegram to my contacts and even blocked suspicious contacts, but it doesn't solve the problem. I disabled pop-ups in Chrome setting but it still didn't help.

How can I disable this pop up for this certain website, or any other solution?

Comment: So you're on a random website when suddenly it sends you a pop up, and after you press it, it opens the Telegram app? Did i get that right? That just sounds like regular ads in the browser and not a telegram issue

Comment: @a yes, it may be a virus. It sometime automatically opens the pop up and then opens telegram. How can I just block a certain website on chrome?

Comment: I didn't quite understood from your previous answer - it happens on random sites, or specific ones? Could you share the website/the join link/screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

The link to open the telegram channel will be there in your **incognito windows tabs**.
Close that tabes from your incognito window.
Then these telegram channels opening automatically when you open chrome browser will be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Go to app settings(settings of your mobile) of telegram and check for defaults
Under applink

Disallow "open the supported link in app".

[image]